# c++ friend conversion function

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, friend, typeconverter

I noticed this webpage says that user defined conversions can be preceded by the keyword "friend"

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

> may include any specifier other than type-specifier or the keyword
>   static, In particular, besides explicit, the specifiers inline,
>   virtual, friend, and constexpr are also allowed.

So I tried it out, but cannot seem to get friend working with conversion operators (the other keywords it mentions do work).

Is the webpage incorrect, or is there a way to do this using the friend declaration?

```
class t_friend_conversion_error
{
  public:
            operator int      ( ) ; //ok
  virtual   operator int *    ( ) ; //ok
  inline    operator int **   ( ) ; //ok
  constexpr operator int **** ( ) ; //ok

  friend    operator char     ( ) ; //error
} ;
```

Comment: Doesn’t it not make sense to use ‘friend’ on the conversion function of a class since that conversion function already has access to the private parts being a member of the class? The operator keyword must be prefixed by some other classname for use of friend to grant additional priveliges..

Answer (score 4):

It seems you cannot have a `static operator char()`. But it does not mean you cannot use `friend`, just put it in an auxiliary class:

```
class t_conversion_helpers
{
    public:   
    operator char     ( ) ;
};

class t_friend_conversion_error
{
    public:
    operator int      ( ) ; //ok
    virtual   operator int *    ( ) ; //ok
    inline    operator int **   ( ) ; //ok
    constexpr operator int **** ( ) ; //ok
    friend    t_conversion_helpers::operator char     ( ) ; //ok
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip!, the example you gave is declaring a friend function, rather than defining a conversion, is that correct? If that is the case then maybe the webpage could remove "friend" from the list of conversion definition prefixes, and add your example as a handy  workaround example?. Would have saved me time,maybe help others?

Comment: @MichaelCollier I agree with you that what is written in reference is a bit unclear, but it still is correct. That paragraph of the reference talks about **declaration**, not **definition**, it even references `decl-specifier-seq`

Comment: Sorry for confusion about decl/defn. What I mean is, does your example declare a "friend conversion" or is it using the underlying ability to declare a friend function?

Comment: To clarify a bit, I'm building a GUI that allows users to build classes from  entities such as "friend function", "conversion" etc. So I think your example would already be covered by the GUI ability to build a friend function, rather than me having to write new code for the GUI to handle this particular type of conversion?

Comment: The reference docs have been updated, both in declaring friend functions in general, and in declaring friend conversion functions. They mention the need to prefix keyword friend with a qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage you linked to now states: "`friend` requires a qualified name: `friend A::operator B();`".

Comment: And A would be the name of some class different from the class ‘operator B()’ is a member of (for use of friend to make sense).